# How to control the size of the default RadioButton in QML?

Tags: qt, radio-button, qml

How do I reduce or control the size of the `RadioButton`s below in a `ColumnLayout` in the simplest possible way?

```
ColumnLayout{
    RadioButton {
        text: "Option1"
        checked: true
    }
    RadioButton {
        text: "Option2"
    }
}
```

All the examples available, lead me into making a complex styled RadioButton. I just want the default one and simply reduce the size.

I am using *Qt 5.12.5*.

Comment: [Layout.preferredWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredWidth-attached-prop) / [Layout.preferredHeight](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredHeight-attached-prop)

Comment: Setting Layout.preferredWidth / Layout.preferredHeight messes up the text of the radio button. Interestingly difficult !

Comment: You should update the code, probably you do something wring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every item has `scale` property.

```
    ColumnLayout {
        scale: 0.75

        RadioButton {
            text: "Option1"
            checked: true
            scale: 0.75
        }
        RadioButton {
            text: "Option2"
        }
    }
```